# Docker compose up slow

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, spring-cloud

I have a spring boot/cloud micro-service application which is similar [here](https://github.com/anilallewar/spring-boot-microservices). And have docker compose to start the service. Now this was running fast about two weeks back and the docker-compose up used to take me 2-3 minutes to start all the application.

But now it's taking me nearly 15 minutes to start the application. I am sure I haven't made any changes in docker configuration is last few weeks.

Any help is appreciable.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Docker version 17.09.1-ce, build 19e2cf6

docker-compose version 1.17.0, build ac53b73

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  config-service:
    image: test/config-service
    mem_limit: 1073741824
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ~/logs/config-service:/app/logs
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-I", "http://config-service:8888"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    depends_on:
      mongo-db:
        condition: service_healthy

  eureka-service:
    image: test/eureka-service
    mem_limit: 1073741824
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ~/logs/eureka-service:/app/logs
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-I", "http://eureka-service:8761"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    depends_on:
      config-service:
        condition: service_healthy

  user-service:
    image: test/user-service
    mem_limit: 1073741824
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ~/logs/user-service:/app/logs
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      eureka-service:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Tomcat log (trimmed as I reached max word limit)

```
    2018-01-18 08:23:00,467 INFO  [main] com.test.userservice.UserServiceApplication : The following profiles are active: docker
2018-01-18 08:23:00,636 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@56aac163: startup date [Thu Jan 18 08:23:00 GMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@e2d56bf
2018-01-18 08:23:11,079 INFO  [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory : Overriding bean definition for bean 'managementServletContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
2018-01-18 08:23:14,462 INFO  [main] org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope : BeanFactory id=ebfc4c4a-204e-3d20-ab06-5ee31c9ae744
2018-01-18 08:23:14,709 INFO  [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-01-18 08:23:16,511 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration$DefaultAsyncConfigurerSupport' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration$DefaultAsyncConfigurerSupport$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf6fe615] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:17,760 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.SleuthAnnotationAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.SleuthAnnotationAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84938e84] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:20,662 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'sleuthAdvisorConfig' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.annotation.SleuthAdvisorConfig] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:20,909 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'security.oauth2.client-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2ClientProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2ClientProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:21,116 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$39780452] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:21,561 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'resourceServerProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:21,985 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b45aee93] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:22,516 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e484b4f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:23,191 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.AsyncDefaultAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6a11f471] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:23,576 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration$TraceOAuthConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceWebClientAutoConfiguration$TraceOAuthConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c72adab1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-18 08:23:30,323 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-18 08:23:30,454 INFO  [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-01-18 08:23:30,460 INFO  [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2018-01-18 08:23:30,949 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-01-18 08:23:30,971 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 30335 ms
2018-01-18 08:23:42,305 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,308 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,308 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'traceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,308 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,308 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,308 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,310 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,310 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,310 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-18 08:23:42,310 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-18 08:24:01,859 INFO  [main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongo-db:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2018-01-18 08:24:01,875 INFO  [main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Adding discovered server mongo-db:27017 to client view of cluster
2018-01-18 08:24:07,610 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5a6059a0b3cb1f00072c45c2', description='null'}-mongo-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:28}] to mongo-db:27017
2018-01-18 08:24:07,613 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5a6059a0b3cb1f00072c45c2', description='null'}-mongo-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo-db:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 10]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=577257}
2018-01-18 08:24:07,614 INFO  [cluster-ClusterId{value='5a6059a0b3cb1f00072c45c2', description='null'}-mongo-db:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Discovered cluster type of STANDALONE
2018-01-18 08:28:53,270 WARN  [main] com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-01-18 08:28:54,188 INFO  [main] com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-01-18 08:28:56,203 WARN  [main] com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-01-18 08:28:56,204 INFO  [main] com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-01-18 08:29:37,452 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@56aac163: startup date [Thu Jan 18 08:23:00 GMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@e2d56bf
2018-01-18 08:29:39,074 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Detected ResponseBodyAdvice bean in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration$ActuatorEndpointLinksAdvice
2018-01-18 08:29:54,522 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-01-18 08:29:54,535 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-18 08:30:02,532 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-18 08:30:02,532 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-18 08:30:05,657 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in exceptionHandler
2018-01-18 08:30:05,657 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected ResponseBodyAdvice implementation in org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration$ActuatorEndpointLinksAdvice
2018-01-18 08:30:26,080 INFO  [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-18 08:33:58,388 INFO  [main] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration$LazyEndpointPathRequestMatcher@723ed581, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6b760460, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7af1cd63, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@667e34b1, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@796065aa, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@62515a47, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@6dc1484, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3c2772d1, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@89c65d5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@28a6301f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@6dba847b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@45673f68, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5a5c128]
2018-01-18 08:34:00,867 INFO  [main] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@766a4535, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7351a16e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@38eb2fb0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4074023c, org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@562457e1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5bb7643d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3ac04654, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@63718b93, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4567e53d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@336365bc, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3721177d]
2018-01-18 08:34:01,272 INFO  [main] org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@35835fa, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2df3c564, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@aac3f4e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@518cf84a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@62e7dffa, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2715644a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4c2869a9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@56f71edb, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1f38957, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7a2e0858, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@b8a7e43]
2018-01-18 08:34:43,897 INFO  [main] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler : Initializing ExecutorService 
2018-01-18 08:34:52,517 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-18 08:34:53,014 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-18 08:34:53,016 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-18 08:34:53,016 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-18 08:34:53,154 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-18 08:34:53,155 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'serviceRegistryEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-18 08:34:53,165 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-18 08:34:53,360 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2018-01-18 08:34:54,090 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
2018-01-18 08:34:54,190 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'serviceRegistryEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint:name=serviceRegistryEndpoint,type=ServiceRegistryEndpoint]
2018-01-18 08:34:54,325 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2018-01-18 08:34:54,561 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=56aac163,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2018-01-18 08:34:54,699 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.endpoint:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
2018-01-18 08:34:58,144 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-01-18 08:34:58,540 INFO  [main] org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2018-01-18 08:35:01,069 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2018-01-18 08:35:12,136 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-01-18 08:35:12,137 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-01-18 08:35:13,882 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2018-01-18 08:35:13,882 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2018-01-18 08:35:16,570 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws.ConfigClusterResolver : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2018-01-18 08:35:17,044 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Disable delta property : false
2018-01-18 08:35:17,044 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2018-01-18 08:35:17,044 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Force full registry fetch : false
2018-01-18 08:35:17,044 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Application is null : false
2018-01-18 08:35:17,045 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2018-01-18 08:35:17,045 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Application version is -1: true
2018-01-18 08:35:17,045 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2018-01-18 08:35:19,108 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : The response status is 200
2018-01-18 08:35:19,109 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2018-01-18 08:35:19,151 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2018-01-18 08:35:19,221 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1516264519221 with initial instances count: 2
2018-01-18 08:35:21,590 INFO  [main] org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry : Registering application user-service with eureka with status UP
2018-01-18 08:35:21,592 INFO  [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1516264521592, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2018-01-18 08:35:21,597 INFO  [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_USER-SERVICE/fad9b0071a33:user-service:8080: registering service...
2018-01-18 08:35:22,235 INFO  [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : DiscoveryClient_USER-SERVICE/fad9b0071a33:user-service:8080 - registration status: 204
2018-01-18 08:35:56,660 INFO  [main] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-18 08:35:56,669 INFO  [main] org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8080
2018-01-18 08:35:56,747 INFO  [main] com.test.userservice.UserServiceApplication : Started UserServiceApplication in 805.764 seconds (JVM running for 807.935)
```

Comment: Any more details than slow? Versions? Dependencies? Configuration? Logs where it shows slowness? You've literally given nothing to help anyone diagnose anything.

Comment: Are you on Mac OS?

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: Version of Spring Cloud and Spring Boot?

Comment: springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE
springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.SR4'

Comment: Maybe if there's something wrong with `eureka-service`, it retries 5 times separated 3seconds each one, so, 15 sec until user service starts because `depends_on:
      eureka-service:
        condition: service_healthy`. Furthermore, this 15sec increases because you have another dependency with `config-service` and mongo. 
Just try to clean all containers `docker container prune`, or exit containers when healthcheck fails.